# Type cast the stdClass object to an array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to send some data from one server to another through json

I am sending multiple data from my server to other server through json and all is working fine but the problem is when I am sending an array. I am trying to send let's say values 1,2,3 as an array but on the other side it seems that I am sending as a stdclass obj. I tried to type cast the object but with no luck.

```
$data["operating_city_ids"]=[1,2,3,4];

$str=(array)$data;

echo (new Rest_smp())->update('promoter', $id, $str);
```

And the update is:

```
public function update($dir, $id, $input)
    {           
        $data = ['id'=>$id, 'data'=>$input];

        $json = $this->call('PUT', '/'.$dir, $data);

        return $json;
    }
```

The result I get is:

```
[operating_city_ids] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [1] => 12345
                    )
```

And I would want something like this:

```
[operating_city_ids] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [1] => 1,2,3,4,5

                        )
```

or

```
[operating_city_ids] => array
                        (
                            [0] => 1
                            [1] => 2
                            ...

                        )
```

I am new to PHP so be gentle if I misunderstood something.

Comment: in "update", the json must be sent via json_decode(... , true) to return an array instead of an stdClass Object.

Comment: nope,not working

Comment: $array=(array) $stdClass ;type cast object convert to array.  ,If convert array to obj $obj=(object) $array;